# Can't fetch javascript file through require.js but browser works fine (500 Server Error)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, requirejs

I am running into an issue where some of my javascript scripts aren't being loaded. In the console it says the `GET` request for the files failed because of a 500 internal server error.

I am using require.js to load modules per page.

This is how I add the scripts to my page:

*Detail.cshtml*

```
@section script {
    <script async data-main="requirejs/product/init" src="/js/libs/require.js"></script>
}
```

These are the logs from my console:

> require.js:1 GET http://localhost:50002/js/requirejs/module/main.js?_=v1 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   req.load @ require.js:1
>   ...
>   onScriptLoad @ require.js:1
>
> require.js:1 Uncaught Error: Script error for "main", needed by: requirejs/product/init
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>      at makeError (require.js:1)
>      at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1)

Now I have verified that `http://localhost:50002/js/requirejs/module/main.js?_=v1` does exist, as in when I visit that link in my browser, I see the javascript file. But for some reason require.js can't read the file.

The request that fails looks like this (if it's relevant at all):

```
General
Request URL:http://localhost:50002/js/requirejs/module/main.js?_=v1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:[::1]:50002
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 31 May 2017 11:00:32 GMT
Server:Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcbmllbHNcRG9jdW1lbnRzXHdlYnNob3AtdGVtcGxhdGVcc3JjXHdlYnNob3AuYmx1ZW5vdGlvbi5ubFxqc1xyZXF1aXJlanNcbW9kdWxlXG1haW4uanM=?=

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,nl;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:fullcss=true; fonts-loaded=true
Host:localhost:50002
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:50002/nl/vazen/feline
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
```

I am honestly stumped as to why the file can be loaded when I manually access it from my browser, but it messes up when require.js tries to load it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you verify if you can access http://localhost:50002/libs/requirejs/require.js and http://localhost:50002/requirejs/product/init.js in browser? Also, do you get the same error when using `require.config()` to set dependencies?

Comment: I can not access those from links from the browser. I'm not sure what you mean bij using `require.config()`, in what file is this located?

Comment: Basically you need to make sure you can access both JavaScript files in browser. It's hard to guess the exact URL not seeing your solution.
There are different ways to set up `RequireJS`, and by `require.config()` I was referring to https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/wiki/Patterns-for-separating-config-from-the-main-module
To help you better, could you upload minimal version of your solution somewhere?